# Multiple textboxes inside an array

Tags: php, mysql

i have been trying to update the values in mysql from text boxes

```
<?php  
$ses_sqlc = ("select * from checks where orderid='".$id."' ");
$resultc = $conn->query($ses_sqlc);
$num_ros = $resultc->num_rows;
while ($rowcc = $resultc->fetch_assoc())
{
?>   
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rowcc['name']; ?></td> 
        <td class="replyBTN">
            <h6 style="color:#000000; cursor:pointer" >+Serial No.</h6>
        </td>
        <td class="appnd" style="display:none;">Enter Serial Nos.
            <table>
                <tr>
                <?php for ($j=0; $j < $rowcc['valuess']; $j++) { ?>
                    <td style="padding-left:5px;">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rowcc['id']; ?>" name="checkid[]" />
                        <input type="text" name="valsno[]" class="form-control" placeholder="1">
                    </td>

                <?php } ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

        <td><?php echo $rowcc['valuess']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $rowcc['remarks']; ?></td>
        <td><input name="midlevelusers[]" id="list11" class="age_agree" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>             

    <?php if (isset($_POST['checkid'])) {
        $item_idCount = count($_POST["checkid"]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $item_idCount; $i++) {

        $valsno = implode(',', $_POST['valsno']);

        $conn->query("UPDATE checks set snos='" . $valsno[$i] . "' WHERE id ='" . $_POST["checkid"][$i] . "'");
        }
    // sno ends
    }
```

Below is the code that i tried so far.

But it not updating rows correctly

Any suggestions would be helpful?

Comment: What have you tried to spot the error? Which parts of that code do not work as expected?

Comment: You should consider using an editor with syntax highlighting, it'll help you quickly spot errors/typo's.

Comment: implode is not working, it is only fetch the value for first input box

Comment: There's no opening PHP block after your HTML and before your PHP-code?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using unescaped user data in your queries like that.

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in the code example. Could you add some error reporting to the update query and let us know if it comes back with anything? You can use: `if (!mysql_query("UPDATE checks set snos='" . $valsno[$i] . "' WHERE id ='" . $_POST["checkid"][$i] . "'", $conn)) { echo mysqli_error($conn); }`

Comment: No error, only if there are two textboxes then value is not inserting with cmman selperated, e.g if i am inserting 1 in first and 2 in second , it only inserts 1

Comment: $valsno = implode(',', $_POST['valsno']);

Comment: `implode()` creates a _string_, so when you then do: `$valsno[$i]`, you're doing it on a string, not on an array.

Comment: $valsno = implode(',', $_POST['valsno'][$i]) does not insert anything.;